# C debugging in CLion using makefiles

Tags: c, debugging, makefile, clion

I've already set up a run configurations using makefile in CLion: [Run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YM71N.png)

But I don't know how to setup a debug configuration this way. I've tried "Custom Build Targets", using default toolchain, but it does not show anything to put in "Build" and "Clean" fields.

So, the question is: how can I debug using only Makefile and CLion configurations?

CLion version is 2020.2.1

Comment: I also tried this guide https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/custom-build-targets.html#custom-rundebug, it seems to work fine, but I can't find an executable file like tscancode on screenshot in last article

Comment: First you need to build target and then find executable in File Manager.